# How do I emphasize his superiority?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

A boy(3 years) I saw in a fun-fair was trying to play in mickey mouse bounce house(precisely speaking clambering a steep slope) suitable for kids older than him, say more than 5 years. I am trying to find a phrase which would mean that he did something which the older kids do because he was determined. I have heard of a phrase *head and shoulders above his peers* but that emphasizes that he is superior to his peers but I want a term which focuses on the equality between him and his seniors. Looking at him, we feel proud that as a young kid, he is doing really great and is equal to big kids playing with him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems **"he could keep up with older kids"** would work.

> Keep up: to manage to do as much or as well as other people

(Longman)

Answer (score 3):

You could say he was *holding his own* among the big kids.

> **Hold your own** (idiom):
>   (1) to ​maintain ​your ​position or ​condition ​despite ​difficulties
>   (2) to be as ​successful as other ​people or things in a ​situation
>   - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold-your-own
>
> **Hold one's own**
>   (1) be sufficiently competent in a certain situation; "He can hold his own in graduate school"
>   (2) maintain one's position and be in control of a situation
>   - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold+one%27s+own

Comment: @AndyT I'll remove it.  It was marked as "American" in the references I checked, and I'm not familiar enough with British English to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

That guy was *precocious*.

Precocious is an adjective, an aberration, that person has attained certain traits at an earlier age than expected in general for his age..It is a neutral word,can be used for both in negative and positive sense..

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a colloquial term and also essentially one which has a positive sentiment attached to it. :)

Comment: _Precocious_ is fine in colloquial speech. I also don’t recall hearing anyone using it negatively, except inasmuch as **any** positive word can be used negatively, as in “Oh, little miss _perfect_ is so _beautiful_ and _smart_ and can do _everything_ so well… God I hate her!”, where both _perfect_, _beautiful_, and _smart_, normally very positive words, are being used disparagingly and become negative in the context. That is of course possible with _precocious_, but barring that type of usage, it generally has quite a positive ring to it, I’d say.

Comment: Other than in the song Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, I don't think I have ever heard *precocious* used in a non-disparaging way. That said, I never knew its definition either.